# CSS Selector : Alternate Row Background Ignoring DIV Tags in the middle

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML at disposal,

```
<section>
     <div class="select"></div>
     <div class="ignore"></div>
     <div class="select"></div>
     <div class="ignore"></div>
     <div class="select"></div>
<section>
```

I wanted alternative background color for the divs whose class is 'select'.

I tried using

```
select: nth-child(odd) {
//
}
```

But this doesn't work, because there is a div with ignore class in the middle. And I am not getting alternate background colors :-(

Comment: `section div:nth-child(odd)`?

Comment: tried that, didn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d8cnvbef/4/ -> In the Fiddle, 'Hai' Message should have alternative color.

Comment: if the structure is alternating `select` and `ignore`, then https://jsfiddle.net/h05a2m7z/ would work